# Decrypt Data From DB Table Encrypted With CryptProtectData in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, encryption

Hello i am trying to fetch data from a **sqlite database** table but the data is protected with **CryptProtectData**.

Can Someone tell me how do i decrypt the data?

```
    Public Sub Name()
    Dim ConnectionString As String = "Data Source=Employee.sqlite"
    Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT dateofbirth From info"
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim con As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(SQLString, con)
    con.Open()
    Dim Reader As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While Reader.Read
        Console.WriteLine(Reader("dateofbirth"))
    End While

End Sub
```

in the above code, the field dateofbirth is encrypted.

Comment: The [`ProtectedData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata(v=vs.110).aspx) class is the .NET wrapper for DPAPI, so the [`Unprotect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh68ketz(v=vs.110).aspx) method can probably be used.  You will need to understand how the `dateofbirth` field was encoded into bytes so that you can reverse the process, since `Unprotect` is going to return the decrypted bytes (e.g. perhaps the input to `CryptProtectData` was a UTF8 encoded string).

Comment: Can you provide me an example please?

Comment: Without knowing the format of the `dateofbirth` data I can only guess... but I added an answer that hopefully will help, or will help you enhance the question with the relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how your data is encoded and stored in the database I can only give a generic example, but hopefully this will get you started and/or point to different questions.  This example assumes that the data stored in the database is a UTF8 encoded string.

```vb
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
'...
Dim Reader As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
While Reader.Read
    ' Get data from BLOB column
    Dim encData As Byte() = DirectCast(rdr("dateofbirth"), Byte())
    ' Decrypt the data using DPAPI for the current user
    Dim outputData As Byte() = ProtectedData.Unprotect(encData, Nothing, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
    ' Convert the decrypted data back to a string using UTF8 encoding
    Dim output As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outputData)
    Console.WriteLine(output)
End While
```

You will need a reference to `System.Security.dll` and the import shown to find the `ProtectedData` class.

Comment: Do i need to install something from NuGet Package to make this code work? because there is red underline in the test ProtectedData

Comment: @BishnuDev Answer updated with imports/reference requirements.

Comment: Assuming "output" in Console.WriteLine should be without quotation... However, this worked for me. Thanks! ;)

Comment: @BishnuDev Yes, that's correct, thanks. Glad it helped.